# Assigning attributes to an environment can lead to surprises?

Tags: r

According to R language definition:

> Unlike most other R objects, environments are not copied when passed
>   to functions or used in assignments. Thus, if you assign the same
>   environment to several symbols and change one, the others will change
>   too. **In particular, assigning attributes to an environment can lead to
>   surprises.**

```
> e = new.env()
> attr(e, "mynumber", TRUE)
NULL
> attr(e, "mynumber") = 555
> attr(e, "mynum")
[1] 555
```

What are the surprises exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its examples such as this where we assign 2 to `e`'s `at` attribute and `f`'s `at` attribute automatically changes too:

```
e <- new.env()
attr(e, "at") <- 1
f <- e
attr(e, "at") <- 2
attributes(f)
## $at
## [1] 2
```

Answer (score 2):

It can also lead to surprises if you change the parent environment, especially if you are relying on inheritance.

```
e <- new.env()
e$foo <- function() {print("bar")}

f <- new.env(parent=e)
g <- f

with(g,foo)()
[1] "bar"
parent.env(f) <- .GlobalEnv
with(g,foo)()
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'foo' not found
```